# Unconditional Quantile Regressions – interpretation

Tags: quantile-regression

I'm using the contributions by Firpo et al. (2009) for my research on determinants of inequality and particularly the effects of cash transfers on income inequality.

With a continuous covariate the interpretation of the coefficient is the following: for each additional unit in the unconditional average the effect on the distributional statistic is beta.

However, since I'm using welfare regimes and therefore pooled countries, I'm standardizing the cash transfers. The doubt I have is about the interpretation of standardized covariate in RIF-OLS: how to interpret it? As the effect of additional standard unit above the unconditional average?

Firpo, S., Fortin, N. M., & Lemieux, T. (2009). [Unconditional quantile regressions](https://www.nber.org/papers/t0339.pdf). *Econometrica*, 77(3), 953-973.